# How are poles of Bessel filter related to cutoff frequency?

Tags: filter, pole-zeroplot

For a 2nd order Bessel low pass, I have a pole-zero map which has a pole couple of the form: \$p_{1/2} = a \pm jb\$.

Can I deduce the cutoff frequency from the pole location? Does it contain any more information?

EDIT: Since the calculation of the cutoff frequency in the answer depends on the filter type I am wondering, if it is possible to determine the cutoff frequency for any kind of 2nd order low pass solely by the pole location (under the assumption they are complex conjugate)?

Comment: I suggest that you read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - you can.
There are filter tables for all the well-known lowpass approximations - including the Thomson-Bessel response. These tables list the relavant pole parameters for the various filter orders.

For second order Bessel response the relevant parameters are

$$Q_p=0.5773,\space \Omega_p=\frac{\omega_p}{\omega_0}=1.732$$

**Explanation**: The pole quality factor \$Q_p\$ is a measure for the angle \$\beta\$ between the pole position and the negative-real axis. We have \$Q_p=\frac12\cos\beta\$ . This angle can also be expressed using the given values for the real part (\$a\$) and the img. part (\$b\$) of the pole.

The normalized angular frequency \$\Omega_p=\frac{\omega_p}{\omega_0}\$ is the ratio of the actual angular pole frequency \$\omega_p\$ divided by the actual cut-off frequency \$\omega_0\$. The actual frequency \$\omega_p\$ is identical to the magnitude of the line which connects the origin and the pole position. This magnitude can also be expressed using the known values for \$a\$ and \$b\$.

In this context, you should note that the above mentioned value \$\Omega_p=1.7320\$ is based on the following **definition of cut-off**: The cut-off angular frequency \$\omega_0\$ is defined as the inverse of the group delay, hence: \$\omega_0=\frac{1}{\tau}\$.

This commonly used definition makes sense because - in most cases - the Bessel response is applied because of its time behaviour (delay filter). This is in contrast to other responses (Butterworth, Chebyshev, ...) where the frequency response matters primarily.

If the **cut-off** frequency \$\omega_0\$ is defined using the **3dB criterion** for the magnitude the following normalized value applies: \$\Omega_p=\frac{\omega_p}{\omega_0}=1.2723\$.

Comment: Since there are two definitions for cutoff frequency. Is there a relation which expresses wo for one definition in terms of wo of the other definition, i.e. something like $$ w_{o-3dB} = \alpha \cdot w_{o-tau}$$ ?

Comment: Thank you very mch for editing .....

Comment: Answer to the first comment (question): No - because there is no singular definition for the cut-off in the time domain....it depends on the application. Example for specification: A Bessel lowpass shall have a group delay ripple (deviation from the basic value) of max. 10% at the frequency f1=1.5kHz.  At the frequency f2=2kHz this lowpass shall have an attenuation of at least 10 dB. Both requirements have to be met at the same time....and it turns out that only a 4th order Bessel filter can fulfill these requirements.